# Installing LiipImagineBundle for Symfony 2.1 using Composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, liipimaginebundle

LiipImagineBundle doesn't seem to have instructions for installing itself using composer ([github page](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle)) so I added

```
"liip/imagine-bundle": "*",
```

to my composer.json and updated. Everything went fine until I tried to register the bundle in appKernel.php with the line

```
new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
```

Php gives the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 24
```

As far as I can see LiipImagineBundle is in the right place in the vendors folder. Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

*Edit I should add I'm using symfony 2.1

Comment: Try to remove your vendor directory, and update again.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the line in composer to this:

```
"liip/imagine-bundle": "*@dev"
```

notice the **@dev** at the end. This tell composer that I am willing to accept "dev" stability

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the developer of the bundle and found that there is a `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` where you can manually add entries and the bundle wasn't there.

This guide was helpful: [Composer Namespaces in 5 Minutes](http://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/)

Comment: Please show (exemplary) the code of that file in your question so it's more clear *how* it solved your issue. Also some notes on the *why* would be nice, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony 2.1.4-DEV and including "liip/imagine-bundle": "*" on the composer.json and updating it works

Answer (score -1):

Did you registered Namespace in `autoload.php` and registered Bundle in `AppKernel.php`? If not the class will be not avialable to use until registration there.

As the documentation says:

```
<?php
// app/autoload.php

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    // ...

    'Imagine'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/imagine/lib',
    'Liip'      => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
));
```

And

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...

        new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
    );
}
```

### Update

Run `composer update` it will regenerate your bootstrap files. tell me if any luck with this.

Comment: I think you had to register namespaces in app/autoload.php before composer came along but not anymore. I should add I'm using symfony 2.1

Comment: I tried adding that to autoload.php just to see and have the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerNamespaces() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\Symfony\app\autoload.php on line 13". Symfony 2.1 uses composer instead of app/autoload.php

Comment: I used 'composer update' to install the bundle. The bundle developer suggested the problem was the autoload of composer was out of sync because a post install routine failed, said to try running composer dump-autoload to force it to dump the autoload data again.